# C Macro to Define Set of Macros

Tags: c, macros

I have a series of debugging macros that may expand as either function calls, or as no-op statements.

```
#define NOOP                   do {} while(0)

#ifdef DEBUG
  #define DEBUG_LOG(a)         log(a)
  #define DEBUG_LOG_HEX(a, b)  log_hex(a, b)
#else
  #define LOG(a)               NOOP
  #define LOG_HEX(a, b)        NOOP
#endif
```

I want a macro which can quickly define module specific versions of these global macros which can be turned on and off via an additional #define. I want to do this at the macro level, because I am in an extremely code size constrained environment.

I know this isn't legal, but I hope it shows what I hope to achieve:

```
#define MODULE_DEBUG(MNAME)                      \\
  #ifdef ##MNAME_DEBUG                           \\
    #define ##MNAME_DEBUG_LOG     DEBUG_LOG      \\
    #define ##MNAME_DEBUG_LOG_HEX DEBUG_LOG_HEX  \\
  #else                                          \\
    #define ##MNAME_DEBUG_LOG     NOOP           \\
    #define ##MNAME_DEBUG_LOG_HEX NOOP           \\
  #endif
```

As an example usage, this would invoke log("foo"). But it would NOOP if DEBUG was not set, or if BLE_DEBUG was not set.

```
#define DEBUG
#define BLE_DEBUG

MODULE_DEBUG(BLE);

BLE_DEBUG_LOG("foo");
```

Comment: Are you willing to trust your compiler to optimize out unreachable code like `if (0) log("stuff");`?

Comment: C macros aren't allowed to have defines (directives in general) in them. I'd go with Nate Eldredge's approach ^.

Comment: I think Nate's approach is interesting. I'll play with it, and see what happens.